# NSCollectionView's collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath: method is never called

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscollectionview

I'm accustomed to iOS's `UICollectionView` and am trying to set up an `NSCollectionView` on OSX without using any storyboards (most tutorials use .xibs, so they're slightly different). The API seems similar, but I am unable to get the collection view to call the dataSource's `collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` method.

I've simplified my original code down to the minimum of what I thought would be needed to get the collection view to call this dataSource method:

```
@import Cocoa;

static NSString * const kCollectionViewControllerItemID = @"ItemID";

@interface CollectionViewItem : NSCollectionViewItem
@end

@implementation CollectionViewItem
@end

@interface CollectionViewController : NSViewController  <NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSCollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[NSCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

    _collectionView = [[NSCollectionView alloc] init];
    [_collectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewItem class] forItemWithIdentifier:kCollectionViewControllerItemID];
    [[self view] addSubview:_collectionView];
    [[self view] addConstraints:@[
                                  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:[self view] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0],
                                  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:[self view] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0],
                                  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[self view] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0],
                                  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[self view] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0],
                                  ]];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //this method is never called
    return [collectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:kCollectionViewControllerItemID forIndexPath:indexPath];
}

@end
```

What is this implementation missing?

EDIT:
To make this easier to reproduce, I set up an example project on GitHub https://github.com/BradB132/OSXCollectionViewTest

Comment: Are the other data source methods being called?

Comment: The `itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath` method is the only one that is not called. I've added a link to a repository with this code sample so you can easily reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out you need to wrap your NSCollectionView inside an NSScrollView:

```
NSScrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
_collectionView = [[NSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
scrollView.documentView = _collectionView;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

The collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath: should be called now.